# How do I make a list print random numbers with the same sentence 5 times?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to print a line 5 times like this.....

```
I just burped 5 times.
I just burped 5 times.
I just burped 5 times.
I just burped 5 times.
I just burped 5 times.
```

However I need to make sure the numbers are different in each line. For example:

```
I just burped 5 times.
I just burped 7 times.
I just burped 1 times.
I just burped 9 times.
I just burped 6 times.
```

the code that I have right now looks like this

```
<h3 style="position: absolute;left:118px;top: 88px;"
    onClick="myFunction()"><button onclick = "myFunction()"> Click Me </button></h3>


    <div id="same"></div>



    <script>

        function myFunction() {
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            var text= " ";
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                text += "The number of times I just burped is " + x +"<br><br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("same").innerHTML = text ;  
        }

    </script>   



</body>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Specifically, what is your result vs what are you expecting instead, or what error message did you get.  Tell us what *specific* issue you are running into.  "it doesn't work" isn't enough detail for us to quickly and easily hone into the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the random number generator inside the for loop.

e.g.

```js
function myFunction() {
  let text = " ";
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    text += "The number of times I just burped is " + x + "<br><br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("same").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<h3 style="position: absolute;left:118px;top: 88px;" onClick="myFunction()"><button onclick="myFunction()"> Click Me </button></h3>

<div id="same"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't ensure that the numbers are different in each line.

Comment: I assumed OP's problem was that the numbers were the same on each line and not random. But if you want unique the solution by @guest271314 would work.

Answer (score 1):

Put the x assignment inside the loop. That way it will change per line.

```
<h3 style="position: absolute;left:118px;top: 88px;"
    onClick="myFunction()"><button onclick = "myFunction()"> Click Me </button></h3>  
    <div id="same"></div>
    <script>
       function myFunction() {
            var text= " ";
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

                text += "The number of times I just burped is " + x +"<br><br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("same").innerHTML = text ;  
        }    
    </script>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array, use `.slice()` to copy the array and `.splice()` to remove an element from the array to set number within result that is not a duplicate of a number previously removed from the array

```html
<h3 style="position: absolute;left:118px;top: 88px;" onClick="myFunction()"><button onclick="myFunction()"> Click Me </button></h3>
<div id="same"></div>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    var text = " ";
    var i;
    for (i = 0, copy = x.slice(); i < 5; i++) {
      text += "The number of times I just burped is " 
              + copy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length), 1)[0] 
              + "<br><br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("same").innerHTML = text;
    delete copy;
  }
</script>
```